# 10.3.9-MariaDB can not query equal operator with special character

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I have a MariaDB database that has a filed TagName with value ~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./';[]\=-`

I had set mode `SET @@SQL_MODE = CONCAT(@@SQL_MODE, ',NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES');`

When I try to created DB in MySQL 8.0.13, this query work well and return 1 row

```
select * from taginfo1 where TagName = '~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./'';[]\\=-`';
```

But in 10.3.9-MariaDB, the query

```
select * from taginfo1 where TagName = '~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./'';[]\\=-`';
```

can not return any result.

Is this an MariaDB issue or I missed some configuration?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle like [this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=ae5e913b8a002970fd2466230f2e39c4) so we can switch between mysql-8.0.13 and mariadb-10.3

Comment: I updated value %~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./'';[]\\=-`%

Comment: Test `SELECT field, HEX(field), 'literal', HEX('literal'), field = 'literal', HEX(field) = HEX('literal') FROM ..` on both servers in desured mode. Look carefully where is a problem.

Comment: I tried this query select * from taginfo where HEX(TagName) = HEX('~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./'';[]\\=-`'); but it is still not correct

Comment: You must search not what, but why.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation about [sql_mode NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-mode/):

> Disables using the backslash character \ as an escape character within
>   strings, making it equivalent to an ordinary character.

Your string has a double backslash in it. In the NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES sql_mode this will be interpreted as a double backslash whereas in the default sql_mode it's interpreted as a single backslash.

Below are some tests with MariaDB 10.3.13 using the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE taginfo1 (id int unsigned PRIMARY KEY, TagName varchar(200));
```

**Default sql_mode**

```
INSERT INTO taginfo1 (id, TagName) VALUES (1, '~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./'';[]\\=-`');
SELECT * FROM taginfo1 WHERE TagName = '~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./'';[]\\=-`';
+----+---------------------------------+
| id | TagName                         |
+----+---------------------------------+
|  1 | ~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./';[]\=-` |
+----+---------------------------------+
```

Note that one backslash has disappeared.

**sql_mode with NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES**

```
SELECT * FROM taginfo1 WHERE TagName = '~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./'';[]\\=-`';
Empty set (0.000 sec)
```

Let's remove one backslash from the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM taginfo1 WHERE TagName = '~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./'';[]\=-`';
+----+---------------------------------+
| id | TagName                         |
+----+---------------------------------+
|  1 | ~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./';[]\=-` |
+----+---------------------------------+
```

Then let's insert a second row while we're in NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode:

```
INSERT INTO taginfo1 (id, TagName) VALUES (2, '~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./'';[]\\=-`');

SELECT * FROM taginfo1 WHERE TagName = '~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./'';[]\\=-`';
+----+----------------------------------+
| id | TagName                          |
+----+----------------------------------+
|  2 | ~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><./';[]\\=-` |
+----+----------------------------------+
```

As far as I can tell, this all works as per the documentation. If you really get different results in 10.3.9, then presumably there was a bug that's been fixed.